# I want to insert list of object type mysql with spring boot

Tags: java, spring

Hello i want to sent request like below postman and must store in database:

```
{
"name":"name1",
"salary":12000,
"address_locations":{
    "addressdetails":
[
{
"line1":"302",
"line2":"VA"
},
{
"line1":"308",
"line2":"VA"
}
,{
"line1":"311",
"line2":"VA"
}

]
}
}
```

do not think about real kind of example just want to do it with rest api crud spring boot JPA.
what type of pojo should i write and how can i get addressdetails data with spring boot hibernate Jpa?

Comment: What kind of DB? What have you done so far? What is your current POJO? What exception are you getting? Where are you stuck.

Comment: @Siddarth Sreeni, i am using mysql db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Pojo class for DTO as below:

```
package com.learning.springbootapp;

import java.util.List;

public class MyPojo {
    private String name;
    private Long salary;
    private List<AddressLocation> addressLocations;

    // getters and setters
}

class AddressLocation {
    private String line1;
    private String line2;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: ,i am getting exception like Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface

Comment: Please post your code here for which you are getting exception, so that can explain better.

Comment: I put @ElementCollection above List<AddressLocation> solved my issued.

Comment: Good to know it solved your issue :)